# Pci-compliance Cross-site Scripting - contact form

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form, cross-site, pci-compliance

Long time viewer, first time posting. I'm new to php and hope someone could be of assistance. I have a pci-compliance issue using a contact form from this website, [Tutorial Stag Contact Form Php Ajax Jquery](http://www.tutorialstag.com/advanced-jquery-contact-form-with-php-support.html) . I'd like to know what I need to do in order to be compliant, I ran the code with control scan and this is what was returned:

```
Summary: 
Cross-Site Scripting

Risk: High (3)
Type: Fritko
Port: 80
Protocol: TCP
Threat ID: 300004

Information From Target:
Regular expression ".{0,1}'.{0,1}">" matched contents of /contactform.php/'">.

Query Parameters

Fritko - '">
Solution:
There are built in functions for different languages that may do the encoding for you. In PHP you can use the htmlspecialchars() function In .Net you can use the Server.HtmlEncode() function.Details:

XSS is a type of computer security vulnerability typically found 
in web applications which allow code injection by malicious web 
users into the web pages viewed by other users. Examples of such 
code include HTML code and client-side scripts. 

An attacker can use this vulnerability to completely alter the 
layout of a particular page for a specific user or to force the 
user to launch malicious javascript. 

Cross site scripting occurs when user input is not properly 
encoded by the application prior to display back to the user. In 
order to fix this issue, the application developers must encode 
most non-alphanumeric user-supplied data into their corresponding 
HTML characters before the data is displayed back to the user. For 
example, " would convert to &quot and < would convert 
to &lt; 

There are built in functions for different languages that may do 
the encoding for you. In PHP you can use the htmlspecialchars() 
function In .Net you can use the Server.HtmlEncode() function.
```

While doing a lot of googling, I got lost in what I should add in order to fix the issue. The code from the website is exactly what I used. Can you guys help me on this? If you go to the website you'll be able to check out the complete code and help me, i'll greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like that you gathered this information with an automated tool. You need to manually look whether or not that information given is a false positive. Therefore you need to learn first what XSS is and you need to learn (read) the code in question. Both are actions which can only be done by yourself (learning) and this is too broad to be answered IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [htmlspecialchars()](http://us.php.net/htmlspecialchars)
This will convert HTML into special characters designated to represent the originals without being evaluated by the browser. This prevents someone from submitting a form with a "name" or "phone number" of lets say

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/changepassword.php?newpass=test123&verify=test123" height=0 width=0>
```

Without escaping the HTML, if this data is outputted to the browser it will be a security issue. If escaped, then the actual text will appear instead of an iframe. (just as it is on this site)

Change:

```
$javascript_enabled = trim($_REQUEST['browser_check']);   
$department = trim($_REQUEST['dept']);   
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);   
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);   
$phno = trim($_REQUEST['phno']);   
$subject = trim($_REQUEST['subject']);   
$msg = trim($_REQUEST['msg']);   
$selfcopy = trim($_REQUEST['selfcopy']);
```

to:

```
$javascript_enabled = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['browser_check']));   
$department = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['dept']));   
$name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']));   
$email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']));   
$phno = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['phno']));   
$subject = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['subject']));   
$msg = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['msg']));   
$selfcopy = trim(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['selfcopy']));
```

Comment: This presumes the data would actually be going into MySQL. If it's being embedded in an email, then mysql_real_escape_string() is worse than useless.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the data isn't going to MySQL. It's just sending to an email address, with the information in plain text.

Comment: Good catch Marc! For some reason in my head I was thinking htmlspecialchars, and typed real_mysql_escape_string() instead.

Comment: Thanks David, I wasn't sure where to put htmlspecialchars() within that code. I'll try this and have them scan it again.

Comment: Regular expression ".{0,1}'.{0,1}">" matched contents of /contactform.php/'"> What is this referring to in the code? Just regular expressions in the php or within the html body?